# How to select cell with specific color in openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Suppose a column has two colors: white and green.

Task: Use openpyxl to select green cells.

I have read the official documentation [Working with styles](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/styles.html#basic-font-colors), but fail to figure out how to do it.

---

There are many minor questions: for example, how to figure out the code of current color?

Comment: There have been similar questions like this in past. It's possible but not easy and you'll need to provide more code than this for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bellow is one possibility to set the (backgroud) color of a **cell**.

In this example, we use the `openpyxl.styles.fills.PatternFill` class.
It applies an uniform fill using a pattern (here, it is the "solid" pattern),
with a foreground color (green), and a background color (not visible
with the solid pattern, but visible with another like 'gray125').

You can also the the `openpyxl.styles.fills.GradientFill` class
to produce a gradient fill…

```
import openpyxl.styles

wb = load_workbook(xls_path)
ws = wb.active

cell = ws["A1"]
cell.fill = openpyxl.styles.PatternFill('solid', openpyxl.styles.colors.GREEN)
```

So, to get the color of the fill pattern, you can read the `fill.fgColor`
(or `fill.bgColor` for background) property.
You get an instance of `openpyxl.style.Color` class.

Call the `rgb` property (it’s a descriptor) to get the RGB color as string.
Note: this value has 4 component: the Alpha color (transparency) and the classic RGB colors.

```
color = cell.fill.fgColor
assert isinstance(color, openpyxl.styles.Color)
assert color.rgb == "0000FF00"  # Green
```

But, all that won’t help you. Because **columns have styles too**.

A worksheet contains a collection of `column_dimensions`.
Each `column_dimensions` contains the properties (styles, etc.)
for one or several columns (the notion of column groups).
The `min` and `max` attributes of a `column_dimensions` give
the column indexes (start and end index of the group, starting at 1).

```
cd = ws.column_dimensions["A"]
assert cd.min == 1 and cd.max == 1
```

Like a cells, you can set the fill pattern of a columns:

```
cd.fill = openpyxl.styles.PatternFill('solid', openpyxl.styles.colors.GREEN)
```

Note: the cell style has higher priority over column style.
In other words, if you set the column style to white, but the cell style to green,
the user will see a green cell.